# How does a String terminate in C?

Tags: c, null-terminated

I know the string in c will be terminated by a character `\0`.

However, if I do `char a[5]="abcd\n"` , where would `\0` be?

Or do I need to reserve at least one position for `\0`, whenever I try to use `char[]` to store a string?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You need to reserve one position for `\0`. So your array should be `a[6]`.

Comment: In your code, `a` is *not a string!* It's just a static byte buffer of length 5, but it misses the zero termination that would make it a string. C allows this (in C++ this initialisation would be invalid).

Comment: @kiner_shah Thank you, and I was also wondering what will happen if I insist to use a[5]? Can I still normally use functions for string?

Comment: If your "string" is not null terminated, it's not a string.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you! So will ``` char a[5]="abcd"``` be considered as a string?

Comment: As @KonradRudolph says, the array is not a string in the sense that all standard C string functions expects it to be, because it doesn't have the terminator. So if you pass it to e.g. `strlen` then you will get *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @ChenYao Yes, in that case it is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
char a[]="abcd\n";
```

without specifying the size to let compiler figure out the buffer size. The actual buffer will have size of 6 to accommodate your 5 bytes + 1 byte for terminating zero. When you type "something" without assignment, compilaer puts that string in a dedicated place in the program with at least 1 zero byte after the last character.

Writing
char a[5]="abcd\n"
is a bad practice because it will cause functions like strcpy() to act in undefined manner as your variable 'a' is not a c string, but just a buffer of characters, which by chance seem to be all printable/visible + terminating \n